# Ошибка vk_api.exceptions.ApiError

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть код:

```
session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : 'test', 'random_id' : '0'})
```

При выполнении кода получаю ошибку:

> vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [17] Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации VK API по [коду ошибки](https://dev.vk.com/reference/errors) 17 сказано:

> Действие требует подтверждения — необходимо перенаправить пользователя на служебную страницу для валидации.

В библиотеке vk_api получить `redirect_uri` можно в объекте `ApiError`

```py
from vk_api.exceptions import ApiError

try:
    session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': 'test', 'random_id': '0'})
except ApiError as e:
    print(e.error["redirect_uri"])
```

Эту ссылку уже открывает пользователь токена в браузере. Пользователь подтверждает и метод можно использовать снова.